# localStorage for theme

Tags: javascript, html, css, themes

I'm adding a dark mode on to my portfolio site and I've been looking at localStorage as a way of saving the choice of dark vs light. I'm pretty new to JS but I've managed to get the toggle working, on click, which I'm really happy with. I feel as though there's some minor thing's I'm missing to make this work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Default HTML:

```
<body id="body" class="light-mode">
// code for content
</body>
```

JS Code:

```
    function sickoMode() {
    var body = document.getElementById("body");
    var currentClass = body.className;
    body.className = currentClass == "dark-mode" ? "light-mode" : "dark-mode";

    localStorage.setItem('body', 'currentClass');
}
```

Comment: Check this link https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/863019/Theme-Selector-Based-on-HTML-Local-Session-Storage

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look at it as soon as I get home